# How do I compile to Flash Player 11.2 to use the new features like Stage3D?

Tags: flash

So there's a lot of great new features supported by Flash Player 11.2, particularly for game development which is great news for myself.

- [Some reading here.](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/03/gameon.html)
  Highlights:

  1. Right-click is enabled now (finally).
  2. *Much* better rendering performance.

This is all wonderful and magical, however I can't work out how to compile to Flash Player 11.2, and can't find much information about it.

In publish settings, this is all I get:

[image]

Using Flash CS5.5 Version 11.5.1.349 (latest).

Do I need to wait for CS6 or am I missing something?

Comment: I think the flash player update is purely client-side. Actionscript itself is not influenced by this update. I have little experience with flash programming, but I'm assuming that the player selection just enforces a minimum version or otherwise optimises everything for a specific version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found instructions to do this below:

- [Adding FP11 Support to Flash Pro CS5 and CS5.5](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html)

Once you install the .mxp located there, you'll be able to publish as FP11:

[image]

And finally be able to make use of impressive libraries like [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/).